# Quaternion rotation gimbal problems in Unreal engine

Tags: c++, rotation, quaternions, unreal-engine4

I am streaming data into unreal engine from an inertial sensor. It outputs UnNormalized quaternion data in the format:

```
 X = 6561.00000
 Y = 6691.00000
 Z = 2118.00000
 W = 2078.00000
```

I am applying this to an actor, in c++, using:

```
 this->SetActorRelativeRotation(rotsQ);
```

And it gives me strange gimbal issues.

When i rotate pitch 90 degrees, it rotates in Pitch.

I rotate 90 degrees in Yaw.

When i rotate pitch 90 degrees, it rotates in Roll.

I have tried Converting it to a FRotator and flipping axes, applying axes one at a time and switching the rotation order. I have tried setting the Actor to 0,0,0 every tick then adding the rotation value. No matter what I do, I see the same thing. Any help here would be very much appreciated!

Could it be a handedness problem? What can i try here?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if your input data from the sensor show change of rotation or its absolute value. If it is an absolute value try using `SetActorRotation` instead of `SetActorRelativeRotation`.

If input data represents delta rotation, try `AddActorLocalRotation` or `AddActorWorldRotation`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The values are absolute rotations.  I have tried using setActorRotation,  and see exactly the same results.  I understood that using quaternions should solve this problem,  but no matter what,  I can't get rid of it!

Comment: Maybe you are rotating around global axis instead of local axis relative to the object? This article explains how to rotate around a custom axis using quaternions. https://ninepointeightgame.com/game-updates/quick-quaternion-tips